# Triple Booting; Windows, Ubuntu, Linux Mint by Windows Installer

Tags: ubuntu, debian, linux-mint, system-installation, dual-boot

I wanted to install Linux Mint 14.1 using the Windows Installer (`mint4win.exe`). I 
copied `mint4win.exe` to HDD, and when I running it, it prompts me to uninstall Ubuntu. Previously I installed Ubuntu 12.10 using Windows Installer.

I want to install it to its own partition.

My partition table is like this:

- Windows 8
- Data
- Data2
- Sync
- Ubuntu
- Linux Mint

What should I do? I don't want risk my Acer Aspire V5-471 by normal install.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I was trying to install Joli Cloud OS along with Linux Mint.

I partitioned the hard disk and installed Linux Mint (primary Linux) on it and use wubi (or windows installer) to install Joli Cloud OS within the windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it two ways:

1) Use virtualization software

2) Use your current partitioning and install OSs directly to partition

Remember to make backup :)

You should have some partitioning knowledge ( mount points ). You will find plenty of info about it.

Quoting from [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/521087/installing-linux-mint-in-one-partition)

> You can simply create a root / partition in your free space when you install Mint then, and avoid creating any other partition (you can decide this during the Linux installation process).
>
> If you have enough RAM memory, you can skip creating a swap partition entirely. If you don't want a separate /home partition, you will simply have your home folder inside the root partition.